# Should i stop my Tasks?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

Good day!

I try to parallel my little example prog- for each 3600 iterations i create Task and starts it.

Should i stop it someway?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n=1000000;
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < n * 360; i++)
        {
            sb.Append("test");
            if (i % 3600 == 0)
            {           
                var task = Factory.GetTask(sb);
                sb.Clear();
                task.Start();
            }

        }
    }

    public static void WriteToFile(StringBuilder Sb)
    {
        // do work;
    }


 public sealed class Factory
    {
        private Factory()
        { 

        }

        public static Task GetTask(StringBuilder Sb)
        {
            return new Task(()=>Program.WriteToFile(Sb));
        }

    }
```

Comment: We don't really know what you're trying to achieve, or what `Factory.GetTask` does. Do you *want* to stop your tasks? If so, on what signal? Have you considered using a cancellation token?

Comment: set Factory class. I want to stop or delete this tasks when this task do work.

Comment: That doesn't really explain much - but there's a standard idiom for task cancellation, and you should really stick with that.

Comment: You want to stop it while its doing work, meaning you want to **cancel** the `Task`?

Comment: No, i just want that wnet task do work that will be deleted. should i type task.Waint() or it runs and deletes automatically? I dont want to get 10k threads in my memory

Comment: May be i should try TaskFactory...